# C# How can we write an independent end tag in xml

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Contrast name=" left minus right">1 -1</Contrast name=" left minus right">
```

This is the result of this code in c#

```
        writer.WriteStartElement("Contrast name=\" left minus right\"");
        writer.WriteString("1 -1");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
```

But I want it in this way..........

```
        <Contrast name=" left minus right">1 -1</Contrast>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write attributes, you can use WriteAttributeString method

```
writer.WriteStartElement("Contrast");
writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "left minus right");
writer.WriteString("1 -1");
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: @Sudhanshu You  welcome, could you mark as correct answer?